# Twists Meshes in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I twist meshes around another mesh as shown in the image below with geometry nodes? I know *Set Curve Tilt* and *Curve to Mesh* nodes could be used to achieve a similar result, but the meshes in my node tree are already generated and modified by other nodes so *Curve to Mesh* will not work.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created two variants for you here:

[image]

One creates the mesh shown with *Geometry Nodes*, and the other twists an existing mesh.

So the answer to your question is:

1. Capture the height of your mesh with the node `Bounding Box`.
2. Map the *Z-position* of each vertex with the maximum height into a range of $0$ - $2\pi$. This is the angle that also increases as a function of height until it reaches a full $360°$ rotation.
3. Rotate the vector on the *Z-axis* with this angle and use that as the position for the node `Set Position`.

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!