# Texture coordinates on 3 profile curves within 1 geometry nodes setup (Default cube rope tutorial)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I must preface this by saying that I have a very limited knowledge of Geo nodes, so this may come off as quite stupid.

I followed Default cubes GN rope tutorial( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VzYMah-nTg ), however I didn't like the outcome of the material.
I then tried to add an existing rope texture that I found to the default cubes geo nodes setup which didn't work for me.

I then saw a post here ( [Texture coordinate on geometry nodes rope from Default Cube's tutorial (texture coordinates over profile curve)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252909/texture-coordinate-on-geometry-nodes-rope-from-default-cubes-tutorial-texture) ) that mentioned how to add proper texture coordinates to a profile curve. I managed to get that working, however I want to create a 3-ply rope with 3 seperate profiles wrapping around eachother.

Is there a way to create proper coordinates for each individual profile seperately within the same geo nodes setup or is this impossible?
[image]

At the moment I am joining geometry of 3 circles and obviously the texture coordinate is off on 2 of the profiles.

I would also like to keep the bezier drawing feature if possible too as I will be drawing these ropes by hand once everything works.

Comment: See if this helps.  Twists Meshes in Geometry Nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265661/twists-meshes-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: Thanks, although I am struggling with the texturing rather than the twisting which I can figure out easily enough.

Comment: Then you may want to start with looking at UV texturing using geometry nodes.

Comment: I followed a previous question about UV texturing through geo nodes, however that was only accounting for a single circle profile curve. I have three which means that one of the profiles has a good UV texture while the other two don't. I cannot figure out how to separately make their UV maps within the same geometry nodes setup.

Comment: I posted an answer here, and @quellenform correctly pointed out  it was a duplicate. I've  reposted to the link he has given in the close-notice. NB. His solution is the more rigorous one.

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry, I really didn't want to be a know-it-all here, but I have really dealt with the topic intensively ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Nothing to apologise for. I know how much work you've put into this. I've just been using the split-curve thing for something else altogether: making a multi-spline _Loft Splines_, with a mixture of cyclic and acyclic splines. I spent ages reconstructing split cyclic splines before realizing _Trim_ would do it..  (dooooh!) .You can even put the end-points back exactly where they came from.