# How do I create a marshmallow twist shape with multiple colours?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, uv, objects

I'm trying to create a twisted marshmallow shape like the one below. However, I can't find any tutorials that are specifically for this. I would like to be able to change the colours individually. I've tried doing the 3 circle method and deleting the inside + merging vertices at centre but it doesn't really turn out like this. Anyone know how to make this?

[image: Twisted Marshmallow shape]

Comment: Alternatively, this can also be solved with Geometry Nodes: [Twists Meshes in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265661/twists-meshes-in-geometry-nodes/265692#265692)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a cylinder with lots of horizontal [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and duplicate the cylinder 4 times. Give each cylinder their own material color and position as shown below. Select all cylinders and join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Set the *Origin* at the center of the geometry and then apply a [`Simple Deform`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html) modifier with an angle 360° and select *Axis* the cylinder is pointing to, which is *Z-axis* in this case. Add [`Array Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) to repeat the pattern.

[image]

[image]

Optionally you could give it this squarish look at the center by temporarily disabling the Simple Deform modifier and selecting the Edge Loops near the center for each cylinder then using Proportional Editing to scale the vertices toward the center.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth answer! Very concise and easy to follow. Appreciate it.